# Emacs Yaml Editing

Tags: emacs, yaml

is there any Emacs lisp add-on that allows me to edit or enter data in yaml file easily.

For example:

```
--- sample yaml file ---
Name : 
Addr :
City :
State:
Zip  :

Phone:
Email
--- End ----
```

When the file is opened in Emacs, the cursor will be automatically placed at the first Yaml key. In this case "Name:",  when I finish entering a name after the "Name:" and hit return, it will automatically move to the next key. in this case "Addr:"

forward / backward tab can be used to move back and forth between keys.

Is there anything out there for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/YamlMode

Answer (score 3):

I gather bits and pieces from the net and got this:

```
(defun yaml-next-field ()
  "Jump to next yaml field"
  (interactive)
  (search-forward-regexp ": *"))
(defun yaml-prev-field ()
  "Jump to next yaml field"
  (interactive)
  (search-backward-regexp ": *"))
(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key yaml-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)
             (define-key yaml-mode-map "\M-\r" 'insert-ts)
             (define-key yaml-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'yaml-next-field)
             (define-key yaml-mode-map (kbd "C-S-<tab>") 'yaml-prev-field)
             ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom macro that does what you want.

It could something like this:

```
;; define named macro
(fset 'jump-next-colon
  [?\C-f ?\C-s ?: ?\C-  ? ])
;; assign shortcut ctrl+alt+j
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-j") 'jump-next-colon)
```

If this is not exactly what you are looking for you can write your own macro. See http://emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

Answer (score 0):

[jump-char](https://github.com/lewang/jump-char) could help.  It lets you jump to next/previous occurrence of a character quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [yaml-pro](https://github.com/zkry/yaml-pro) package.